# Getting authenticated username in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm using Django's built in user who is in my application authenticates and uses some service. Now my problem is, I want to get current user's username and write it to database. Here I've used such method that mentioned User model as a ForeignKey, but it is assigning to database as an empty data. But I want to write current user's name. Here are my codes:

`views.py`:

```
@login_required(login_url='sign_in')
def upload_document(request):
    context = {}
    form = UploadDocumentForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadDocumentForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('index')
    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'upload_document.html', context)
```

`models.py`:

```
class OriginalDocument(models.Model):
    document = models.FileField(upload_to='static/original_document', blank=False)
    document_title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    student_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    teacher_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    document_type = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    university = models.ForeignKey(University, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    checked_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.document_title

forms.py:

class UploadDocumentForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = OriginalDocument
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ['date_added', 'checked_by']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UploadDocumentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: it mean you want to assign logged in user to the `checked_by`, right?

Comment: @MKPatel, yes, right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then you have to write `save_model` into your `admin.py` as below...

```
class OriginalDocumentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if not change:
            obj.checked_by = request.user
        obj.save()
admin.site.register(OriginalDocument, OriginalDocumentAdmin)
```

Or Try it with override save() method of form as below...

```
class UploadDocumentForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = OriginalDocument
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ['date_added', 'checked_by']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
        super(UploadDocumentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = super(UploadDocumentForm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.request:
            obj.checked_by = self.request.user
        obj.save()
        return obj
```

Comment: now it says ```'OriginalDocument' object has no attribute 'request'```

Comment: Can you please add your forms.py also

Comment: Please remove it from `exclude`.

Comment: but in this case, user will see all users' name and can select other's name

Comment: Okk, then kepp it as it is.

Comment: why so agressive ?))

Comment: Its my nature :))

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: ```Instance of 'UploadDocumentForm' has no 'request' member```

Comment: Yes, it's because of i forgot to add request in `__init__`, Now i updated it. So, now 100% it will work :)

Comment: Always, Happy Codding :)

Comment: Man, hello, have a good day. Can you check please my this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61156491/django-form-save-is-not-creating-modelform ? Last days my question reach very few people, and can't tag someone. Please, help me.

Comment: I think you got the solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Finally, after an hours of searching I've found a package named django-currentuser ([link is here](https://pypi.org/project/django-currentuser/)) which is pretty simple to use and a project that I really wanted. This package helped me to get username of logged in user and use it as a field in model.

Comment: Nyc and easy solution.